# Using an Alias in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, alias, decode, ora-00904

I have a query which is meant to show me any rows in table A which have not been updated recently enough. (Each row should be updated within 2 months after "month_no".):

```
SELECT A.identifier
     , A.name
     , TO_NUMBER(DECODE( A.month_no
             , 1, 200803 
             , 2, 200804 
             , 3, 200805 
             , 4, 200806 
             , 5, 200807 
             , 6, 200808 
             , 7, 200809 
             , 8, 200810 
             , 9, 200811 
             , 10, 200812 
             , 11, 200701 
             , 12, 200702
             , NULL)) as MONTH_NO
     , TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(B.last_update_date, 'YYYYMM')) as UPD_DATE
  FROM table_a A
     , table_b B
 WHERE A.identifier = B.identifier
   AND MONTH_NO > UPD_DATE
```

The last line in the WHERE clause causes an "ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier" error. Needless to say, I don't want to repeat the entire DECODE function in my WHERE clause. Any thoughts? (Both fixes and workarounds accepted...)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

This is not possible directly, because chronologically, WHERE happens *before* SELECT, which always is the last step in the execution chain.

You can do a sub-select and filter on it:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT A.identifier
    , A.name
    , TO_NUMBER(DECODE( A.month_no
      , 1, 200803 
      , 2, 200804 
      , 3, 200805 
      , 4, 200806 
      , 5, 200807 
      , 6, 200808 
      , 7, 200809 
      , 8, 200810 
      , 9, 200811 
      , 10, 200812 
      , 11, 200701 
      , 12, 200702
      , NULL)) as MONTH_NO
    , TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(B.last_update_date, 'YYYYMM')) as UPD_DATE
  FROM table_a A
    , table_b B
  WHERE A.identifier = B.identifier
) AS inner_table
WHERE 
  MONTH_NO > UPD_DATE
```

Interesting bit of info moved up from the comments:

> There should be no performance hit.
>   Oracle does not need to materialize
>   inner queries before applying outer
>   conditions -- Oracle will consider
>   transforming this query internally and
>   push the predicate down into the inner
>   query and will do so if it is cost
>   effective. – [Justin Cave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10397/justin-cave)

Answer (score 16):

```
 SELECT A.identifier
 , A.name
 , TO_NUMBER(DECODE( A.month_no
         , 1, 200803 
         , 2, 200804 
         , 3, 200805 
         , 4, 200806 
         , 5, 200807 
         , 6, 200808 
         , 7, 200809 
         , 8, 200810 
         , 9, 200811 
         , 10, 200812 
         , 11, 200701 
         , 12, 200702
         , NULL)) as MONTH_NO
 , TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(B.last_update_date, 'YYYYMM')) as UPD_DATE
FROM table_a A, table_b B
WHERE .identifier = B.identifier
HAVING MONTH_NO > UPD_DATE
```

Comment: `HAVING` is the real answer. `HAVING` is the clause checker for calculated columns, like `COUNT`, `MAX` and other expressions in the `SELECT` query, because it filters the final fetched data.

Answer (score 11):

Or you can have your alias in a `HAVING` clause

Comment: This would be an interesting approach, can you give any code?

Comment: the same rule as to where applies, so this is not a solution.

Comment: I'm stuck on MySQL (5.5), don't know if this applies to Oracle. BUT:  
`SELECT CONCAT(names, surname) AS x FROM clients HAVING x LIKE '%a%'`  
 works, while `SELECT CONCAT(names, surname) AS x
FROM clients
WHERE x LIKE '%a%'` fails ("Unknown column 'x' in 'where clause'")

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative approach to you can do:

```
WITH inner_table AS
(SELECT A.identifier
    , A.name
    , TO_NUMBER(DECODE( A.month_no
      , 1, 200803 
      , 2, 200804 
      , 3, 200805 
      , 4, 200806 
      , 5, 200807 
      , 6, 200808 
      , 7, 200809 
      , 8, 200810 
      , 9, 200811 
      , 10, 200812 
      , 11, 200701 
      , 12, 200702
      , NULL)) as MONTH_NO
    , TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(B.last_update_date, 'YYYYMM')) as UPD_DATE
  FROM table_a A
    , table_b B
  WHERE A.identifier = B.identifier)

    SELECT * FROM inner_table 
    WHERE MONTH_NO > UPD_DATE
```

Also you can create a permanent view for your queue and select from view.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW_1 AS (SELECT ...);
SELECT * FROM VIEW_1;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to effectively define a variable that can be used in both the SELECT, WHERE and other clauses.

A subquery doesn't necessarily allow for appropriate binding to the referenced table columns, however OUTER APPLY does.

```
SELECT A.identifier
     , A.name
     , vars.MONTH_NO
     , TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(B.last_update_date, 'YYYYMM')) as UPD_DATE
FROM table_a A
     , table_b B ON A.identifier = B.identifier
OUTER APPLY (
   SELECT
        -- variables
        MONTH_NO = TO_NUMBER(DECODE( A.month_no
                     , 1, 200803 
                     , 2, 200804 
                     , 3, 200805 
                     , 4, 200806 
                     , 5, 200807 
                     , 6, 200808 
                     , 7, 200809 
                     , 8, 200810 
                     , 9, 200811 
                     , 10, 200812 
                     , 11, 200701 
                     , 12, 200702
                     , NULL))
) vars
WHERE vars.MONTH_NO > UPD_DATE
```

Kudos to [Syed Mehroz Alam](https://smehrozalam.wordpress.com/2010/01/25/referring-computedcalculated-columns-in-the-where-and-group-by-clause/).