# Sql query on rownum

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00904, rownum

```
SELECT instmax
FROM
  (SELECT instmax ,rownum r
  FROM
    ( SELECT instmax FROM pswlinstmax ORDER BY instmax DESC NULLS LAST
    )
  WHERE r = 2
  );
```

### After execution it's giving this error:

```
ORA-00904: "R": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 39 Column: 8
```

why it's giving this error??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because aliases are not supported in the WHERE clause of the same query. So instead write your query like:

```
SELECT instmax
FROM 
  (SELECT instmax ,rownum r 
  FROM 
    ( SELECT instmax FROM pswlinstmax ORDER BY instmax DESC NULLS LAST 
    )  
) WHERE r = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can't reference to a second row using a `rownum = 2` condition. You can either select first two rows by specifying a `where rownum < 3` condition, or you may wrap it in another query and reference your `rownum` as an ordinary column from over there.

Then, you can't reference a column alias in a `where` clause of a subquery this alias was assigned.
You can either bring it one level up:

```
SELECT instmax
  FROM (SELECT instmax, rownum r
          FROM (SELECT instmax
                  FROM pswlinstmax
                 ORDER BY instmax DESC NULLS LAST)
         )
         WHERE r = 2;
```

or just avoid this reference

```
-- this will return first two rows
SELECT instmax
  FROM (SELECT instmax, rownum r
          FROM (SELECT instmax
                  FROM pswlinstmax
                 ORDER BY instmax DESC NULLS LAST)

         WHERE rownum < 3
         );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference a column alias in the where clause like that.

The rownum won't quit work that way either.  Try something like this:

```
select instmax from
(
  SELECT instmax, row_number(instmax) order by (instmax desc nulls last) rownumber
  FROM pswlinstmax
)
where rownumber = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

@Amit is right. Because Oracle first evaluates the WHERE condition, then SELECT. You have to do sub-select.

instead of:

```
SELECT instmax
FROM(
  SELECT instmax ,rownum r
  FROM (SELECT instmax FROM pswlinstmax ORDER BY instmax DESC NULLS LAST)
  WHERE r = 2
  );
```

do the following:

```
SELECT instmax
FROM ( SELECT instmax ,rownum r
       FROM ( SELECT instmax FROM pswlinstmax ORDER BY instmax DESC NULLS LAST )
)
WHERE r = 2
;
```

...r is now visible to the WHERE clause.
Propably this question is identicial/similar/duplicate for this:

[Using an Alias in a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356675/using-an-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

A common way to get lets say the top five highly paid employees.

```
SELECT ename,sal FROM   emp
WHERE  rownum <= 5
ORDER BY sal DESC;
```