# How can I select 10th, 20th, 30th ... row of the result of another select query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table with a column `to`, `from` and `ID`. I need to select only rows with every 10th `ID` which is from `A` to `B`.

Comment: If your DBMS supports Windowed Aggregate Function you can simply use a `ROW_NUMBER` modulo 10

Comment: What's your DBMS, does it support ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: then it's ok for ROW_NUMBER you can just go like dnoeth said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select * from 
(select * from table where from = 'A' and to ='B' order by ID)
where mod(rownum/10,1) = 0
```

It first takes only those from 'A' to 'B', then giving them rownums, and selecting only those in the 10th 20th ETC places..

Comment: You have to use order by: (select * from table where from = 'A' and to ='B' ORDER BY ID)

Comment: Good. You could have used `mod(rownum,10) = 0`.

Comment: @sagi its not working..I found something in another post  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963129/how-to-use-rownum

Answer (score -1):

Or you can just use

```
select from, to, id 
from table1 
where id like'%0' and from ='A' and to = 'B'
```

Comment: Who said the ID's are continuously ? he wants the 10th not id = 10 and id = 20