# How to implement conditional select in sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

How to fetch every 10th row from a table i.e. 10th,20th etc. **But if there are less than 10 rows in that table, It should fetch the last row.**

This can be an advance form of this query present in this question -
[How can I select 10th, 20th, 30th ... row of the result of another select query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873334/how-can-i-select-10th-20th-30th-row-of-the-result-of-another-select-query/34873693#34873693)

I have done something like this for selecting every 10th row  -

```
select case_id  
from 
  (select case_id,rownum as seq 
   from table 
   where from = 'A' and to ='B' 
   order by ID
   )
where mod(seq,10) = 0
```

**But if there are less than 10 rows in the result of inner query, It should fetch the last row.**

OBS: database - Oracle 12c

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a code writing service. If you have code that doesn't work, post a question on SO. But "write this code for me" is off-topic here.

Comment: I would create a temp table with rownum in, then write your script based on that temp table.

Comment: The question has been edited, looks ok now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT ColumnA,
       ColumnB,
       ColumnC
FROM   ( 
  SELECT ROWNUM rn,
         COUNT(*) OVER ( ORDER BY NULL ) mx,
         q.ColumnA,
         q.ColumnB,
         q.ColumnC
  FROM   (
    SELECT ColumnA,
           ColumnB,
           ColumnC
    FROM   your_table
    ORDER BY ColumnA
  ) q
)
WHERE  MOD( rn, 10 ) = 0
OR     ( mx = rn AND mx < 10 );
```