# SQL Server query add sequential number to resuls

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sequential-number

I have emergency contact information attached to contact records that I am making into their own contact records.

I need to assign a temporary id to the new contact records for migration purposes.

I was hoping to do this within my SQL query that retrieves the data for creating the new records.

I found references to updating the SQL table to add a new column, but that's not what I want. I can do it after in Excel, but would prefer a one step process.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Check these : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15963129/how-to-use-rownum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a one time thing you can use `row_number()`

```
SELECT 
  *,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) as TempID
FROM YourTable
WHERE...
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I asked... Is there any way to tell it what # to start at?

Comment: @dbNeophyte Yes just do something `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY SomeColumn) + 10`

Comment: Fantastic!  Just what I needed, and much simpler than what I found. thanks to marc_s for his suggestions too