# Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT logcount, logUserID, maxlogtm
   , DATEDIFF(day, maxlogtm, GETDATE()) AS daysdiff
FROM statslogsummary
WHERE daysdiff > 120
```

I get

> "invalid column name daysdiff".

Maxlogtm is a datetime field.  It's the little stuff that drives me crazy.

Comment: not sure for mysql, but maybe the alias needs to be wrapped in ticks `\`daysdiff\``.

Answer (score 290, accepted):

```
SELECT
   logcount, logUserID, maxlogtm,
   DATEDIFF(day, maxlogtm, GETDATE()) AS daysdiff
FROM statslogsummary
WHERE ( DATEDIFF(day, maxlogtm, GETDATE() > 120)
```

Normally you can't refer to field aliases in the `WHERE` clause. (Think of it as the entire `SELECT` including aliases, is applied after the `WHERE` clause.)

But, as mentioned in other answers, you can force SQL to treat `SELECT` to be handled before the `WHERE` clause. This is usually done with parenthesis to force logical order of operation or with a Common Table Expression (CTE):

Parenthesis/Subselect:

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
(
   SELECT
      logcount, logUserID, maxlogtm,
      DATEDIFF(day, maxlogtm, GETDATE()) AS daysdiff
   FROM statslogsummary   
) as innerTable
WHERE daysdiff > 120
```

Or see Adam's answer for a CTE version of the same.

Comment: This is not possible directly, because chronologically, WHERE happens before SELECT, which always is the last step in the execution chain. REFER - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356675/using-an-alias-in-a-where-clause

Comment: afaik if the alias in the select is a correlated subquery this will work while the CTE solution won't.

Comment: As Pascal mentioned in his answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38822328/282887, you can use HAVING clause which seems to work faster than subqueries.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor The `HAVING` answer doesn't work in most SQL environments, including MS-SQL which this question is about. (In T-SQL, `HAVING` requires an aggregate function.)

Comment: I never knew you _couldn't_ reference aliases until I came across this issue just now. Love the workaround... does this have any major performance implications?

Comment: A subquery in the FROM clause is called _derived table_.

Comment: @Mr.Boy This shouldn't have significant performance implications. SQL should be able to optimize and pull the outer where into the plan appropriately. But with SQL performance, it's always good to test.

Answer (score 97):

If you want to use the alias in your `WHERE` clause, you need to wrap it in a sub select, or [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx):

```
WITH LogDateDiff AS
(
   SELECT logcount, logUserID, maxlogtm
      , DATEDIFF(day, maxlogtm, GETDATE()) AS daysdiff
   FROM statslogsummary
)
SELECT logCount, logUserId, maxlogtm, daysdiff
FROM LogDateDiff
WHERE daysdiff > 120
```

Comment: Do you happen to know how this fairs efficiency wise? Is there extra overhead using a CTE?

Comment: A CTE is just prettier syntax for a sub-query, so the performance would be similar to that.  In my experience, the performance difference has not been something that has concerned me for operations like this, but it should be fairly simple to test it in your environment to see if your specific table/query is adversely affected with this vs. calling out the formula specifically in the where clause.  I suspect you will not notice a difference.

Comment: CTEs are super nice until you try to use one as a subquery. i've had to resort to creating them as views to nest them. i consider this a serious SQL shortcoming

Answer (score 22):

The most effective way to do it without repeating your code is use of ***HAVING*** instead of ***WHERE***

```
SELECT logcount, logUserID, maxlogtm
   , DATEDIFF(day, maxlogtm, GETDATE()) AS daysdiff
FROM statslogsummary
HAVING daysdiff > 120
```

Comment: I think using `HAVING` on aliases is not standard (it does works on MySQL, though). Specifically, I think it does not work with SQL Server.

Comment: SQL Server: `[S0001][207] Invalid column name 'daysdiff'`

Comment: SQL Server: `[S0001][8121] Column 'day' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: @Vadzim - I just get the error `Invalid column name '<name>'.` Either way, it doesn't work in SQL Server...

Answer (score 11):

If you don't want to list all your columns in CTE, another way to do this would be to use [`outer apply`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
select
    s.logcount, s.logUserID, s.maxlogtm,
    a.daysdiff
from statslogsummary as s
    outer apply (select datediff(day, s.maxlogtm, getdate()) as daysdiff) as a
where a.daysdiff > 120
```

Answer (score 9):

How about using a subquery(this worked for me in Mysql)?

```
SELECT * from (SELECT logcount, logUserID, maxlogtm
   , DATEDIFF(day, maxlogtm, GETDATE()) AS daysdiff
FROM statslogsummary) as 'your_alias'
WHERE daysdiff > 120
```

Answer (score 7):

HAVING works in MySQL
according to documentation:

> The **HAVING** clause was added to SQL because the WHERE keyword could not
>   be used with aggregate functions.

Comment: The question is about sql-server though

Comment: despite the question being about SQL Server, this answer was very helpful for us using mysql who got to here by google! Google doesnt index the question tags, so thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 5):

You could refer to column alias but you need to define it using `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT s.logcount, s.logUserID, s.maxlogtm, c.daysdiff
FROM statslogsummary s
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEDIFF(day, s.maxlogtm, GETDATE()) AS daysdiff) c
WHERE c.daysdiff > 120;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=9d5b89549b45111d3f0a6cc115388afe)**

Pros:

- single definition of expression(easier to maintain/no need of copying-paste)
- no need for wrapping entire query with CTE/outerquery
- possibility to refer in `WHERE/GROUP BY/ORDER BY`
- possible better performance(single execution)

Comment: its worth to mention that it only works in SQL Server

Comment: @MartinZinovsky Question is tagged with `sql-server` and `t-sql` :)

Answer (score 2):

For me, the simplest way to use an ALIAS in the WHERE clause is to create a sub-query and select from it instead.

Example:

```
WITH Q1 AS (
    SELECT LENGTH(name) AS name_length,
    id,
    name
    FROM any_table
)

SELECT id, name, name_length FROM Q1 WHERE name_length > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Came here looking something similar to that, but with a CASE WHEN, and ended using the where like this: `WHERE (CASE WHEN COLUMN1=COLUMN2 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END) = 0` maybe you could use `DATEDIFF` in the `WHERE` directly. 
Something like:

```
SELECT logcount, logUserID, maxlogtm
FROM statslogsummary
WHERE (DATEDIFF(day, maxlogtm, GETDATE())) > 120
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **HAVING** clause because the **WHERE** keyword cannot be used with aggregate functions.

```
SELECT
    logcount,
    logUserID,
    maxlogtm,
    DATEDIFF(day, maxlogtm, GETDATE()) AS daysdiff
FROM statslogsummary
HAVING daysdiff > 120
```