# Using nested query result in parents where clause

Tags: t-sql

I have this query with an sub query `as clicks`
I want to do then `where clicks > 0`, but I get an error that this is not an recognized column.

```
SELECT top 10 *, (select count(*) FROM po_events aeclk WITH(NOLOCK) where (aeclk.[source] = ae.[source]) as clicks

FROM archived_events ae with(NOLOCK) 
where clicks > 0
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree with the comment that this is a possible duplicate, I'd also like to point out that correlated subqueries can be inefficient; killing two birds with one stone, you could do something like:

```
SELECT TOP 10
        ae.*
      , aeclk.clicks
FROM    archived_events ae
        JOIN ( SELECT   source
                      , COUNT(*) AS clicks
               FROM     po_events
               GROUP BY source
             ) aeclk ON aeclk.[source] = ae.[source]
WHERE   clicks > 0
```