# SQL 'Invalid column name ' error, with inner select

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have the following SQL:

```
SELECT A.*, 
(SELECT answer FROM [tblAnswers] B 
WHERE  B.memberID = A.memberID AND QuestionID = 3) AS ethnicity
FROM [tblMembers] A  
WHERE 
LOWER(gender) = 'm' 
AND ethnicity = 'Sephardi'
```

and i get the error `Invalid column name 'ethnicity'` referring to the last reference to that column.

Question: How come this column is not available to the `WHERE` clause?

I know that if i do the following, it works:

```
SELECT A.*, 
(SELECT answer FROM [tblAnswers] B WHERE  B.memberID = A.memberID AND QuestionID = 3) AS ethnicity
FROM [tblMembers] A  
WHERE
LOWER(gender) = 'm' 
AND convert(nvarchar, (SELECT answer FROM [tblAnswers] B WHERE  B.memberID = A.memberID AND QuestionID = 3)) = 'Sephardi'
```

Comment: You can't, it's a limitation of sql server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161938/how-to-use-alias-column-name-in-where-clause-in-sqlserver

Comment: I see little reason _not_ to use a simple join, actually. It will also solve your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a column name you've just assigned in the `SELECT` clause in the following `WHERE` clause. As a general case you can put it in a subquery and then use the column name:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT A.*, 
    (SELECT answer FROM [tblAnswers] B 
    WHERE  B.memberID = A.memberID AND QuestionID = 3) AS ethnicity
    FROM [tblMembers] A  
    WHERE LOWER(gender) = 'm' 
) s
WHERE ethnicity = 'Sephardi'
```

This query might be better suited to a `JOIN` though:

```
SELECT A.*, t.answer AS ethnicity
FROM [tblMembers] A  
LEFT JOIN tblAnswers t ON b.memberID = A.memberID AND QuestionID = 3
WHERE LOWER(gender) = 'm' AND t.answer = 'Sephardi'
```

Comment: thanks. i would need `LEFT JOIN` as these secondary rows may not exist. i have 3 of these subquery fields to filter with. which method is better resource-wise?

Comment: Personally I use a `JOIN` 100% of the time - I'm sure there are cases where a subquery might be better but I'm yet to come across one in practice.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use "Computed" columns in your where clause without specifically referencing the entire computation (query, case, etc).

You should join the Query table instead of subquerying it:

```
Select A.*, B.answer
From tblMembers A
    Inner Join tblAnswers B on A.memberID = B.membeID and A.QuestionID = 3
Where Lower(gender) = 'm'
    and B.answer = 'Sephardi'
```

Comment: Why `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Habit really, no other reason. It could equally be both in this case. I've updated the select to be inner given the specific scenario.