# not able call alias column name in where condition in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
WITH cte1
AS (SELECT
  tbl.EmpID,
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(tbl.LeaveTypeId) = 'a' THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
    ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)
  END AS 'Absent',
  CASE
    WHEN (MIN(tbl.LeaveTypeId) IS NOT NULL OR
      MIN(tbl.LeaveTypeId) <> '') THEN MIN(tbl.LeaveDesc)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS 'Leave',
  CASE
    WHEN (MIN(tbl.outime) IS NULL) AND
      (MIN(tbl.LeaveTypeId) IS NULL) THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
    ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)
  END AS 'InOut',
  CASE
    WHEN CONVERT(char(5), MIN(tbl.InTime), 108) <> '00:00' THEN MIN(tbl.InTime)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS 'S1IN',
  MIN(tbl.outime) AS 'S1OUT',
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(tbl.InTime) = MAX(tbl.InTime) THEN NULL
    ELSE MAX(tbl.InTime)
  END AS 'S2IN',
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(tbl.outime) = MAX(tbl.outime) THEN NULL
    ELSE MAX(tbl.outime)
  END AS 'S2OUT',
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(tbl.InTime) > DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, MIN(tbl.P_Date))) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(time, DATEADD(n, MIN(sd.S1SL), MIN(sd.S1Start)))) THEN DATEDIFF(n, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, MIN(tbl.P_Date))) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(time, DATEADD(n, MIN(sd.S1SL), MIN(sd.S1Start)))), MIN(InTime))
    ELSE 0
  END AS 'LateBy',
  CASE
    WHEN MAX(tbl.OuTime) < DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, MIN(tbl.P_Date))) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(time, DATEADD(n, -MIN(sd.S2EL), MIN(sd.S2End)))) THEN DATEDIFF(n, MAX(OuTime), DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, MAX(tbl.P_Date))) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(time, DATEADD(n, -MIN(sd.S2EL), MIN(sd.S2End)))))
    ELSE 0
  END AS 'EarlyBy',
  MIN(emp.EmpFullName) AS 'EmpFullName',
  MIN(tbl.P_Date) AS 'P_Date',
  MIN(emp.nation_id) AS 'nation_id',
  MIN(emp.dept_id) AS 'dept_id',
  MIN(emp.desig_id) AS 'designation_id',
  MIN(emp.tradecd) AS 'tradecd',
  MIN(emp.comp_id) AS 'comp_id',
  MIN(emp.section_id) AS 'section_id',
  MIN(emp.location_id) AS 'location_id',
  MIN(emp.emplcatgry) AS 'emplcatgry',
  (SELECT
    HODName
  FROM Department
  WHERE Dept_id = MIN(emp.dept_id))
  AS 'deptHOD',
  (SELECT
    HODEmail
  FROM Department
  WHERE Dept_id = MIN(emp.dept_id))
  AS 'deptEmail',
  (SELECT
    ManagerName
  FROM Location
  WHERE Location_id = MIN(emp.location_id))
  AS 'LocManager',
  (SELECT
    Email
  FROM Location
  WHERE Location_id = MIN(emp.location_id))
  AS 'LocEmail',
  (SELECT
    LocationName
  FROM Location
  WHERE Location_id = MIN(emp.location_id))
  AS 'Location',
  (SELECT
    LocType
  FROM Location
  WHERE Location_id = MIN(emp.location_id))
  AS 'LocType',
  (SELECT
    MinWorkingHour
  FROM Location
  WHERE Location_id = MIN(emp.location_id))
  AS 'Minworkhr'
FROM tblattendance tbl
INNER JOIN employees emp
  ON emp.empid = tbl.empid
INNER JOIN Company cmp
  ON cmp.comp_id = emp.comp_id
INNER JOIN ShiftDetails sd
  ON emp.ShiftCode = ISNULL((SELECT
    ShiftCode
  FROM Shift_Calender
  WHERE nFingerPrintId = emp.empid
  AND C_Date = tbl.p_date)
  , sd.ShiftCode)
  AND sd.DayOfWeek = DATENAME(dw, tbl.p_date)
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), tbl.p_date, 112) BETWEEN '20151101' AND '20151101'
AND emp.status <> 'terminated'
GROUP BY tbl.p_date,
         tbl.EmpID) 


SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN S1IN IS NOT NULL AND
      S1OUT IS NOT NULL AND
      S2IN IS NOT NULL AND
      S2OUT IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(n, S1IN, S1OUT) + DATEDIFF(n, S2IN, S2OUT)
    WHEN S1IN IS NOT NULL AND
      S1OUT IS NOT NULL AND
      S2IN IS NULL AND
      S2OUT IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(n, S1IN, S1OUT)
    ELSE 0
  END AS 'TotalHrs'
FROM cte1 
WHERE (Absent = 1
OR InOut = 1 
OR LateBy > 0
OR EarlyBy > 0)
AND LocType = 'Retail Store'  
AND Location =
              CASE 'Lite N Lamps'
                WHEN '0' THEN Location
                ELSE 'Lite N Lamps'
              END
```

n this query i want to add one more condition like

**AND LocType = 'Retail Store'  and TotalHrs=0** but showing error

Invalid column name 'TotalHrs'.

How i can resolve this issue.if any help is very appreciable,thanks in advance

Comment: Use a cte, or derived table.

Comment: i used cte ,but not getting

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use alias column name in where clause in sqlserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161938/how-to-use-alias-column-name-in-where-clause-in-sqlserver)

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple CTE's in following:

```
WITH cte1
AS (SELECT
  tbl.EmpID,
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(tbl.LeaveTypeId) = 'a' THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
    ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)
  END AS 'Absent',
  CASE
    WHEN (MIN(tbl.LeaveTypeId) IS NOT NULL OR
      MIN(tbl.LeaveTypeId) <> '') THEN MIN(tbl.LeaveDesc)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS 'Leave',
  CASE
    WHEN (MIN(tbl.outime) IS NULL) AND
      (MIN(tbl.LeaveTypeId) IS NULL) THEN CONVERT(bit, 1)
    ELSE CONVERT(bit, 0)
  END AS 'InOut',
  CASE
    WHEN CONVERT(char(5), MIN(tbl.InTime), 108) <> '00:00' THEN MIN(tbl.InTime)
    ELSE NULL
  END AS 'S1IN',
  MIN(tbl.outime) AS 'S1OUT',
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(tbl.InTime) = MAX(tbl.InTime) THEN NULL
    ELSE MAX(tbl.InTime)
  END AS 'S2IN',
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(tbl.outime) = MAX(tbl.outime) THEN NULL
    ELSE MAX(tbl.outime)
  END AS 'S2OUT',
  CASE
    WHEN MIN(tbl.InTime) > DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, MIN(tbl.P_Date))) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(time, DATEADD(n, MIN(sd.S1SL), MIN(sd.S1Start)))) THEN DATEDIFF(n, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, MIN(tbl.P_Date))) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(time, DATEADD(n, MIN(sd.S1SL), MIN(sd.S1Start)))), MIN(InTime))
    ELSE 0
  END AS 'LateBy',
  CASE
    WHEN MAX(tbl.OuTime) < DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, MIN(tbl.P_Date))) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(time, DATEADD(n, -MIN(sd.S2EL), MIN(sd.S2End)))) THEN DATEDIFF(n, MAX(OuTime), DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, MAX(tbl.P_Date))) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), CONVERT(time, DATEADD(n, -MIN(sd.S2EL), MIN(sd.S2End)))))
    ELSE 0
  END AS 'EarlyBy',
  MIN(emp.EmpFullName) AS 'EmpFullName',
  MIN(tbl.P_Date) AS 'P_Date',
  MIN(emp.nation_id) AS 'nation_id',
  MIN(emp.dept_id) AS 'dept_id',
  MIN(emp.desig_id) AS 'designation_id',
  MIN(emp.tradecd) AS 'tradecd',
  MIN(emp.comp_id) AS 'comp_id',
  MIN(emp.section_id) AS 'section_id',
  MIN(emp.location_id) AS 'location_id',
  MIN(emp.emplcatgry) AS 'emplcatgry',
  (SELECT
    HODName
  FROM Department
  WHERE Dept_id = MIN(emp.dept_id))
  AS 'deptHOD',
  (SELECT
    HODEmail
  FROM Department
  WHERE Dept_id = MIN(emp.dept_id))
  AS 'deptEmail',
  (SELECT
    ManagerName
  FROM Location
  WHERE Location_id = MIN(emp.location_id))
  AS 'LocManager',
  (SELECT
    Email
  FROM Location
  WHERE Location_id = MIN(emp.location_id))
  AS 'LocEmail',
  (SELECT
    LocationName
  FROM Location
  WHERE Location_id = MIN(emp.location_id))
  AS 'Location',
  (SELECT
    LocType
  FROM Location
  WHERE Location_id = MIN(emp.location_id))
  AS 'LocType',
  (SELECT
    MinWorkingHour
  FROM Location
  WHERE Location_id = MIN(emp.location_id))
  AS 'Minworkhr'
FROM tblattendance tbl
INNER JOIN employees emp
  ON emp.empid = tbl.empid
INNER JOIN Company cmp
  ON cmp.comp_id = emp.comp_id
INNER JOIN ShiftDetails sd
  ON emp.ShiftCode = ISNULL((SELECT
    ShiftCode
  FROM Shift_Calender
  WHERE nFingerPrintId = emp.empid
  AND C_Date = tbl.p_date)
  , sd.ShiftCode)
  AND sd.DayOfWeek = DATENAME(dw, tbl.p_date)
WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10), tbl.p_date, 112) BETWEEN '20151101' AND '20151101'
AND emp.status <> 'terminated'
GROUP BY tbl.p_date,
         tbl.EmpID) 
, cte2 AS
(
SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN S1IN IS NOT NULL AND
      S1OUT IS NOT NULL AND
      S2IN IS NOT NULL AND
      S2OUT IS NOT NULL THEN DATEDIFF(n, S1IN, S1OUT) + DATEDIFF(n, S2IN, S2OUT)
    WHEN S1IN IS NOT NULL AND
      S1OUT IS NOT NULL AND
      S2IN IS NULL AND
      S2OUT IS NULL THEN DATEDIFF(n, S1IN, S1OUT)
    ELSE 0
  END AS 'TotalHrs'
FROM cte1 
WHERE (Absent = 1
OR InOut = 1 
OR LateBy > 0
OR EarlyBy > 0)
AND LocType = 'Retail Store'  
AND Location =
              CASE 'Lite N Lamps'
                WHEN '0' THEN Location
                ELSE 'Lite N Lamps'
              END
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte2
WHERE TotalHrs=0 --your alias condition or you can move all where clause here
```