# SQL where nested select not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `Customers` table with `CustomerID` and `CustomerName`.

I then have a `Orders` table with `CustomerID`, `datetime OrderPlaced` and `datetime OrderDelivered`.

Bearing in mind that not all customers have placed orders, I would like to get a list of `CustomerName`, `OrderPlaced` and `OrderDelivered` but only for customers that have placed orders and whose orders have already been delivered, and only the most recent `OrderPlaced` per customer.

I started by doing (fully aware that this does not implement the `OrderDelivered` limitation to it yet, but already not doing what I want):

```
SELECT CustomerID,
    (SELECT TOP 1 OrderDelivered 
        FROM Orders ORDER BY OrderDelivered DESC) AS OrderDelivered
FROM Customer
WHERE OrderDelivered IS NOT NULL
```

But already MS SQL doesn't like this, it says that it doesn't know what `OrderDelivered` is on the `WHERE` clause.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use alias column name in where clause in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161938/how-to-use-alias-column-name-in-where-clause-in-sql-server)

Comment: `TOP 1 OrderDelivered  ORDER BY OrderDelivered ` is equivalent to `MAX(OrderDelivered)`. You don't need a subquery for this, join the tables and group by CustomerID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would move your subquery into the `FROM` and use `CROSS APPLY`. Then you can far more easily reference the column:

```
SELECT C.CustomerID,
       O.OrderDelivered
FROM Customer C
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 OrderDelivered 
                  FROM Orders oa
                  WHERE oa.CustomerID = C.CustomerID --Guess column name for orders
                    AND O.OrderDelivered IS NOT NULL
                  ORDER BY O.OrderDelivered DESC) O;
```

As, however, this is a `CROSS APPLY`, then the results will already be filtered; so no need for the `WHERE`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the most recent delivered order, then one method uses `apply`:

```
select c.*, o.OrderPlaced, o.OrderDelivered
from customer c cross apply
     (select top (1) o.*
      from orders o
      where o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID and 
            o.OrderDelivered is not null
      order by o.OrderPlaced desc
     ) o;
```

Comment: . . . . You need to write `CROSS/OUTER` prior to `apply`  otherwise `SQL Server` will throw error.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using the `OVER` clause (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql).

```
DECLARE @customers TABLE (CustomerId INT, CustomerName NVARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @orders TABLE (CustomerId INT, OrderPlaced DATETIME, OrderDelivered DATETIME)

INSERT INTO @customers VALUES
    (1, 'a'),
    (2, 'b')

INSERT INTO @orders VALUES
    (1, '2019-01-01', null),
    (2, '2019-01-03', '2019-02-01'),
    (2, '2019-01-05', null)

SELECT
    c.CustomerName,
     -- Latest OrderPlaced
    FIRST_VALUE(o.OrderPlaced)
        OVER(PARTITION BY c.CustomerId ORDER BY o.OrderPlaced DESC) AS OrderPlaced,
    -- The matching OrderDelivered
    FIRST_VALUE(o.OrderDelivered)
        OVER(PARTITION BY c.CustomerId ORDER BY o.OrderPlaced DESC) AS OrderDelivered
FROM @customers c
INNER JOIN @orders o ON o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
WHERE o.OrderDelivered IS NOT NULL
```