# Can we use alias in subselect as value

Tags: sql, alias

Why cant I use alias name as value in where clause in subquery. Is there another way to use alias in similar way in this example?

```
SELECT 
tm.att1 as aliasName1,

tm.att2 as aliasName2,

CASE WHEN tm.att3='A1' THEN 'A' WHEN tm.att3='B1' THEN 'B' ELSE 'C' END as aliasName3,

(SELECT COLUMN FROM TABLE WHERE TABLE_ID = '9999' AND TABLE_CODE = aliasName3) as aliasName4

FROM TABLE_MAIN tm

WHERE tm.id='11111'
```

Comment: You might want to include the entire query above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use alias column name in where clause in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161938/how-to-use-alias-column-name-in-where-clause-in-sql-server)

Comment: @Shmiel no unfortunatelly, because in that case they dont associate an alias with the column name