# WHERE clause to select from AS part of the query

Tags: mysql, sql

When I don't use `WHERE` clause query works fine. How can I make it work with `WHERE` clause? Is it too ambitious?

Thanks

**ERROR**:

```
[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'claims.client_name' in 'where clause'
```

**SQL:**

```
SELECT
(
    CASE
        WHEN client = 'Driver' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM driver WHERE id = claims.client_id)
        WHEN client = 'Passenger' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM passengers WHERE id = claims.client_id)
        WHEN client = 'Thirdparty' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM thirdparty WHERE id = claims.client_id)
        WHEN client = '' THEN  NULL
    END
) AS client_name

FROM claims

WHERE (client_name LIKE '%john%')
```

Comment: post your table structure by using `explain claims;`

Comment: You can't refer alias name in WHERE clause. Check the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause

Comment: Using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` would probably be best in this case.

Comment: you should try this `WHERE (claims.client_name LIKE '%john%')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
WHERE (client_name LIKE '%john%')
```

with

```
HAVING (client_name LIKE '%john%')
```

Comment: Such an easy and simple solution. Never thought about it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN client = 'Driver' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM driver WHERE id = claims.client_id)
        WHEN client = 'Passenger' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM passengers WHERE id = claims.client_id)
        WHEN client = 'Thirdparty' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM thirdparty WHERE id = claims.client_id)
        WHEN client = '' THEN  NULL
        END AS client_name FROM claims WHERE client_name LIKE '%john%'
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an alias in the where clause. Generally you would repeat the code which you give the alias to and put that in.

ie, instead of putting `"WHERE client_name LIKE '%john%'"` you could try:

```
WHERE (CASE
         WHEN client = 'Driver' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM driver WHERE id =
         claims.client_id)
         WHEN client = 'Passenger' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM passengers WHERE id = 
         claims.client_id)
         WHEN client = 'Thirdparty' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM thirdparty WHERE id =
         claims.client_id)
         WHEN client = '' THEN  NULL 
       END) LIKE '%john%'
```

I haven't tried this in the development tool, so it's possible it needs a bit of polishing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use alias name directly in WHERE clause. Check the answers [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause). Unfortunately you can't use CTE which is available in SQL server either, instead you can use
temporary tables.

Try the below statement

```
SELECT tmp.* FROM
(
   SELECT CASE
        WHEN client = 'Driver' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM driver WHERE id = claims.client_id)
        WHEN client = 'Passenger' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM passengers WHERE id = claims.client_id)
        WHEN client = 'Thirdparty' THEN (SELECT fullname FROM thirdparty WHERE id = claims.client_id)
        WHEN client = '' THEN  NULL
    END AS client_name FROM claims
) AS tmp
WHERE tmp.client_name LIKE '%john%'
```