# Column aliases in where clause giving invalid column name error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is a simple question that I'm hung up on. I want to know if I can create a column alias and then use it in my `WHERE` clause, i.e.:

```
SELECT TRACTOR, CONVERT(VARCHAR, ORDER) AS NUMBER
FROM TABLE
WHERE NUMBER = '4'
```

Keep in mind this is just an example of what I'm trying to do. The query I'm running is a bit more complex, but just the basic idea of how to create a variable and then use it in a clause.

My question is about the aliased columns in the where clause. I have a query that looks for an invoice number in one database and matches it the first 7 digits of a field in another database. The query worked fine when we only had 6 digits but now that we have 7, I'm getting an error and I'm trying to rewrite the query in a different manner.

Comment: For starters, please stop using lazy declarations like [`VARCHAR` with no length](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx). Next, you can't reference an alias in the `WHERE` clause. Finally, if `ORDER` is numeric, why do you want to use a string?

Comment: I was just making a quick generic query, sorry. Also, order is actually a string, ex: 1234567A or 1234567B

Comment: are you actually asking about variables? Or are you asking more about aliased columns in the where clause?

Comment: [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: more so aliased columns in the where clause. I have a query that looks for an invoice number in one database and matches it the first 7 digits of a field in another database. The query worked fine when we only had 6 digits but now that we have 7, I'm getting an error and I'm trying to rewrite the query in a different manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at: http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/working-variables-t-sql-part-1

The basic syntax of variables would be like so:

```
declare @id int
select @id = 1

select *
from myTable
where id = @id
```

EDIT: in case you're actually asking about column aliases in your where clause, and not sql variables, take a look at this SO question: [Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

EDITx2:

for your specific case (assuming asking about column aliases) you could do the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TRACTOR, CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), ORDER) AS NUMBER
    FROM TABLE
) someTableAlias
WHERE NUMBER = '4'
```

Though you may want to rethink your column names... i *think* number and order are both reserved words, and should be avoided where possible.  you can get around these for the most part by using [order] and [number] I believe, but still best to avoid reserved words as columns/tables/whatevers.

Comment: +1 for being able to see through the mystery of what OP was on about.

Answer (score 6):

Re-using aliased columns is a great use case for `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT t.TRACTOR, CxA.Num
FROM TABLE t
CROSS APPLY
  (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ORDER)) CxA(Num)
WHERE CxA.Num = '4'
```

Anything in a `CROSS APPLY` can be referenced in the `SELECT`, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, etc with some limitations (normally if you have aggregation in the `CROSS APPLY` expression).