# SQL Server Paging query using a column alias

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a query that I can then use for a paging system here is the query as it stands

```
SELECT   
   SLCustomerAccountID, 
   CustomerAccountNumber, 
   CustomerAccountName, 
   (MainTelephoneAreaCode +  MainTelephoneSubscriberNumber) AS PhoneNumber,
   Row_Number() over (order by CustomerAccountName) as RowIndex 
FROM         
   SLCustomerAccount
WHERE   
   CustomerAccountName LIKE '%green%' 
   AND RowIndex BETWEEN 10 AND 30
ORDER BY 
   CustomerAccountName
```

This query errors with

> Invalid column name 'RowIndex'.

because I am trying to use the alias, but I am not sure of the correct way to set this so I can use the data that is in the column `RowIndex`

Here is what the query returns without the where clause

```
   ID1      ID2      NAME    Number  Row number
__________________________________________
| 12374927| 00010014|Some name| ******| 1|
| 51744   | 6631    |Same name| ******| 2|
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use an alias in the `WHERE` (only in the `ORDER BY`). But you can access it from a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(

    SELECT SLCustomerAccountID, 
           CustomerAccountNumber, 
           CustomerAccountName, 
           (MainTelephoneAreaCode +  MainTelephoneSubscriberNumber) AS PhoneNumber,
           Row_Number() over (order by CustomerAccountName) as RowIndex 
    FROM   SLCustomerAccount
    Where CustomerAccountName LIKE '%green%' 
)
SELECT SLCustomerAccountID, 
        CustomerAccountNumber, 
        CustomerAccountName, 
        (MainTelephoneAreaCode +  MainTelephoneSubscriberNumber) AS PhoneNumber
FROM CTE
WHERE RowIndex Between 10 AND 30
ORDER BY CustomerAccountName
```

Comment: Might as well add a `TOP 30` in the CTE to limit the number of rows. And consider the difference between filtering for 'green' in the CTE or the main SELECT.

Comment: You can use `TOP` and `ORDER BY` in a CTE, in this case it may speed things up a lot if the table is massive, like it may be in a telecoms environment, given that the main SELECT only requires the first 30 rows.

Comment: @AjVJsy: but it's already ordered by `CustomerAccountName`, so the optimizer picks only the 20 rows(10-30) from the result. Do you have a link where it's documented that this can be more efficient? I've never applied a `TOP` clause + additonal `ORDER BY` in the definition of a CTE if i filter by row-number.

Comment: I'd have to look into that, Tim, I don't have any vast tables to test with! Thanks for the opportunity to re-examine what I thought I knew :)

Comment: @TimSchmelter hi thanks for the response, quick note i had to put the line (MainTelephoneAreaCode +  MainTelephoneSubscriberNumber) AS PhoneNumber  ad just selecting MainTelephoneAreaCode  and MainTelephoneSubscriberNumber and keep the concatenated version under that but apart from that works great, Do you know what the scalability and performance  of a solution like this will be?

Comment: @Oisian2: it all depends on your indexes, but in general a CTE with row_number which does not reference itself (or is recursive) is very efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Query executes in following order in SQLSERVER-

```
1. FROM
2. ON
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP
7. HAVING
8. SELECT
9. DISTINCT
10. ORDER BY
11. TOP
```

so here in this case **WHERE** clause will be executed before the **SELECT** clause. So the alias column name will not be available in WHERE clause.