# SQL ROW_NUMBER OVER syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have this:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vwmain.ch) as RowNumber,
    vwmain.vehicleref,vwmain.capid,
    vwmain.manufacturer,vwmain.model,vwmain.derivative,
    vwmain.isspecial,
    vwmain.created,vwmain.updated,vwmain.stocklevel,
    vwmain.[type],
    vwmain.ch,vwmain.co2,vwmain.mpg,vwmain.term,vwmain.milespa
FROM vwMain_LATEST vwmain 
INNER JOIN HomepageFeatured 
  on vwMain.vehicleref = homepageFeatured.vehicleref 
WHERE homepagefeatured.siteskinid = 1
  AND homepagefeatured.Rotator = 1
  AND RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY homepagefeatured.orderby
```

It fails on "Invalid column name RowNumber"

Not sure how to prefix it to access it?

Thanks

Comment: You just want the first row?  A `top` or `limit` might be simpler.

Comment: You can't use the alias of a column directly on the `WHERE`, you either use a derived table `SELECT .... FROM (<your query here>) T WHENRE RowNumber = 1` or you can use a `CTE`. Also, @user1389596 is right, you should just use `TOP 1`

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is probably trying to use this to remove duplicates... in  which case you'll need `partition by`.. .instead of `TOP`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reference the field like that.  You can however use a subquery or a common-table-expression:

Here's a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vwmain.ch) as RowNumber,
        vwmain.vehicleref,vwmain.capid,
        vwmain.manufacturer,vwmain.model,vwmain.derivative,
        vwmain.isspecial,
        vwmain.created,vwmain.updated,vwmain.stocklevel,
        vwmain.[type],
        vwmain.ch,vwmain.co2,vwmain.mpg,vwmain.term,vwmain.milespa,
        homepagefeatured.orderby
    FROM vwMain_LATEST vwmain 
        INNER JOIN HomepageFeatured on vwMain.vehicleref = homepageFeatured.vehicleref 
    WHERE homepagefeatured.siteskinid = 1
       AND homepagefeatured.Rotator = 1
) T
WHERE RowNumber = 1
ORDER BY orderby
```

---

Rereading your query, since you aren't partitioning by any fields, the `order by` at the end is useless (it contradicts the order of the ranking function).  You're probably better off using `top 1`...

Comment: Better you can add the `TOP 1` answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using top:

```
  SELECT top 1 vwmain.vehicleref,vwmain.capid,
        vwmain.manufacturer,vwmain.model,vwmain.derivative,
        vwmain.isspecial,
        vwmain.created,vwmain.updated,vwmain.stocklevel,
        vwmain.[type],
        vwmain.ch,vwmain.co2,vwmain.mpg,vwmain.term,vwmain.milespa,
        homepagefeatured.orderby
    FROM vwMain_LATEST vwmain 
        INNER JOIN HomepageFeatured on vwMain.vehicleref =   homepageFeatured.vehicleref 
    WHERE homepagefeatured.siteskinid = 1
       AND homepagefeatured.Rotator = 1
    ORDER BY homepagefeatured.orderby
```

Comment: May be `ORDER BY vwmain.ch ASC` will make more sense

Answer (score 0):

(**EDIT**: This answer is a nearby pitfall. I leave it for documentation.)

Have a look here: [Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

This is the same situation.

It is a matter of how the sql query is parsed/compiled internally, so your field alias names are not known at the time the where clause is interpreted. Therefore you might try, in reference to the example above:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vwmain.ch) as RowNumber,
vwmain.vehicleref,vwmain.capid, vwmain.manufacturer,vwmain.model,vwmain.derivative, vwmain.isspecial,vwmain.created,vwmain.updated,vwmain.stocklevel, vwmain.[type],
vwmain.ch,vwmain.co2,vwmain.mpg,vwmain.term,vwmain.milespa

FROM vwMain_LATEST vwmain 
  INNER JOIN HomepageFeatured on vwMain.vehicleref = homepageFeatured.vehicleref 

WHERE homepagefeatured.siteskinid = 1
  AND homepagefeatured.Rotator = 1
  AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY vwmain.ch) = 1

ORDER BY homepagefeatured.orderby
```

Thus you see your expression in the select statement is exactly reused in the where clause.

Comment: You cannot use `window` function in `where` clause

Comment: So this is a wrong answer. Thanks. I won't delete the question so others may see the pitfall.

Comment: `Sub-select` or `cte` is the way to go