# Postgres how to implement calculated column with clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I need to filter by calculated column in postgres. It's easy with MySQL but how to implement with Postgres SQL ?

pseudocode:

```
select id, (cos(id) + cos(id)) as op from myTable WHERE op > 1;
```

Any SQL tricks ?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have CTEs but that's one way to get around repeating the expression. You can also use an inline view/derived table/nested table or whatever they call it in MySQL

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you don't want to repeat the expression, you can use a derived table:

```
select *
from (
   select id, cos(id) + cos(id) as op 
   from myTable 
) as t 
WHERE op > 1;
```

This won't have any impact on the performance, it is merely syntactic sugar required by the SQL standard.

Alternatively you could rewrite the above to a common table expression:

```
with t as (
  select id, cos(id) + cos(id) as op 
  from myTable 
)
select *
from t 
where op > 1;
```

Which one you prefer is largely a matter of taste. CTEs are optimized in the same way as derived tables are, so the first one might be faster especially if there is an index on the expression `cos(id) + cos(id)`

Comment: If indexes are important it might be a good idea to just use to an explicit range of id values between +/-1.0471975511965977461542144610932 radians.

Comment: Is this more efficient than the below answer where the calculation is in the where clause?

Answer (score 8):

```
select id, (cos(id) + cos(id)) as op 
from selfies 
WHERE (cos(id) + cos(id)) > 1
```

You should specify the calculation in the `where` clause as you can't use a `alias`.

Comment: For those that are interested, this solution is quite a bit faster than using the derived table above.