# Use alias in OR clause SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, alias

I am attempting to use a column alias in an OR clause, but I keep getting the error: "Invalid column name 'TEAM NAME'". I've seen threads about using aliases in WHERE clauses, but I'm not sure if OR is possible.
Here's what I'm working with:

```
[TEAM NAME] = CASE WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('RY','BR') THEN 'Team 1'
WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('JS','ND') THEN 'Team 2' 
WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('QV','VE') THEN 'Team 3'
WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('FB','RX') THEN 'Team 4'
ELSE '-' END,
```

and here is my OR clause

```
AND (U.Player IN ('Tom Thumb','Wallace Gromit') OR [Team Name] <> '-')
```

Comment: I think your best bet is wrapping your main current query in a subquery and putting that part on the outside, if you want to use the alias. Alternatively, chuck that line in a having clause without using the alias. e.g. `having u.player in ('Tom Thumb','Wallace Gromit') or max(L.city) in ('ry','br','js','nd','qv','ve','fb','rx')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you have to write it out.  PS this should be in the `HAVING` clause:

```
AND (U.Player IN ('Tom Thumb','Wallace Gromit') OR 
CASE WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('RY','BR') THEN 'Team 1'
WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('JS','ND') THEN 'Team 2' 
WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('QV','VE') THEN 'Team 3'
WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('FB','RX') THEN 'Team 4'
ELSE '-' END,
 <> '-')
```

OR

```
AND (U.Player IN ('Tom Thumb','Wallace Gromit') OR 
MAX(L.City) NOT IN ('RY','BR','JS','ND','QV','VE','FB','RX'))
```

Alternatively you could treat your whole query as a Subquery and select from that

```
Select  * from (myquery) s where (U.Player IN ('Tom Thumb','Wallace Gromit') OR [Team Name] <> '-')
```

[Similar issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

[Check out a basic example here](http://rextester.com/LQEN20473)

Comment: Note: Aggregates go in a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: I am referring to the first two parts of your answer. They need to be in a having clause or they will still produce an error.

Comment: @zlk smart, 100% correct.  updated

Comment: Your second solution worked well for me once I put it in the HAVING clause-- thanks a lot to both of you for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried aliasing it this way in the `SELECT` statement?

```
CASE WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('RY','BR') THEN 'Team 1'
     WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('JS','ND') THEN 'Team 2' 
     WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('QV','VE') THEN 'Team 3'
     WHEN MAX(L.City) IN ('FB','RX') THEN 'Team 4'
     ELSE '-' END AS [TEAM NAME]
```

If this is part of a subquery or CTE, it will provide you access to this column in the outer query request data from it.

Also, the `WHERE` clause is run before the `SELECT` clause in any query/subquery, so the alias will not be available in the `WHERE` clause if it was made in the `SELECT` clause at the same query/subquery.