# Mysql select where syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to fix the syntax in the code below.

```
$key = 4;
$column = "five_year";

$query_for_rate = "SELECT $column key FROM $usertable WHERE key=$key";

$get_rate = mysql_query($query_for_rate) or die(mysql_error());

echo $query_for_rate. "<br>";
echo $get_rate;

if($get_rate){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($get_rate)){

echo $row;

    }
}
```

error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'key FROM current_rates WHERE key=4' at line 1

---

Thank you for the replies. The query is now working, I think. When I echo $get_rate I get "Resource id #5".  My problem now is I cannot get my while loop to produce any results. Thank you!

Comment: `key` is reserved. Rename your column, also columns in the `select` need to be separated by commas, or are you trying to make that an alias?

Comment: Also, you're missing a comma before key.

Comment: you might accept some answer, or write your own?

Answer (score 1):

Key is a reserved word. You need to quote it with backticks.

```
$query_for_rate = "SELECT $column `key` FROM $usertable WHERE `key`=$key";
```

However I suspect that won't work but rather you'll need to do this instead.

```
$query_for_rate = "SELECT $column `key` FROM $usertable WHERE `$column`=$key";
```

Since you need to reference the actual column name not what you aliased it as.

Comment: `$column` != `key`.

Comment: According to what he wrote $column is aliased as key.

Comment: You can't use a column alias in the `where`... or you couldn't.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause As I read it OP wants to select `five_year` and `key`.

Comment: @chris85 please read my answer and you'll see I'm well aware of that.

Comment: That doesn't show that. `SELECT $column key` is invalid, for multiple reasons.

Comment: We're talking about different things here, but yes I forgot to backtick the alias or quote it.