# SQL for absolute value greater than some value

Tags: sql

The following SQL works:

```
select
  column1
from
  table1
where
  column1 > 10
```

The following doesn't:

```
select
  abs(column1 - column2) column_diff
from
  table1
where
  column_diff > 10
```

Why? How should I fix it? All I want to say is that 'give me all the rows with the absolute value of the difference of the two columns greater than 10'. Thanks.

Comment: Use a subquery, CTE, or put the expression in the `where` clause.  That is how SQL works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query won't work because sql engine will compile your query in following steps:

1. `from` clause
2. `where` clause
3. `select` clause

So, while executing `where` clause, alias `column_diff` won't be available hence the query won't work.

Solution:

```
select 
     abs(column1 - column2) as column_diff
         from
           table1
               where
                 abs(column1-column2) >10;
```

Hope it helps!