# STR_TO_DATE as column, but column not found

Tags: mysql, sql

Whats wrong in this query:

```
select *, STR_TO_DATE(start, '%d/%m/%Y') as date_format from dates where date_format >= 2018-03-19
```

error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'date_format' in 'where clause'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using column alias in WHERE clause of MySQL query produces an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942571/using-column-alias-in-where-clause-of-mysql-query-produces-an-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a column alias in a `where` clause.  MySQL has an extension where you can do so in a `having` clause (without doing any aggregation).  So you can do:

```
select d.*, STR_TO_DATE(start, '%d/%m/%Y') as date_format
from dates d
having date_format >= '2018-03-19';
```

The normal advice is to repeat the expression:

```
select d.*, STR_TO_DATE(start, '%d/%m/%Y') as date_format
from dates d
having STR_TO_DATE(start, '%d/%m/%Y') >= '2018-03-19';
```

However, I would strongly recommend that you change the structure of the table.  The date should not be stored as a string.  You can easily fix this:

```
update dates
    set start = STR_TO_DATE(start, '%d/%m/%Y');

alter table dates modify column start date;
```

Comment: another solution are views.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use date_format as it is just given name but `STR_TO_DATE(start, '%d/%m/%Y')`

Answer (score 0):

try this way

`date_format` is not field so use `start` instead of `date_format`

```
select *, STR_TO_DATE(start, '%d/%m/%Y') as date_format from dates where start >= 2018-03-19
```