# Using Alias in Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large case in my select statement, that ends as either 1 or 0, and has an alias name "x". I want to check if "x" = 1 in my WHERE statement, but I know that aliases cannot be used in the where statement. Is my only way of checking for this condition to include the original case statement in the WHERE clause?

Comment: To be more precise, you can use aliases in the where clause as long as it is a table alias. You are referring to a column alias.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Comment: if it is only 1 or 0 and you have it in the where clause, why do you need to select it?

Comment: Since this is essentially returning a bit why not skip that column and just have a where clause? Seems you don't really need it in the return values, or at least not as the result of your case expression.

Comment: Put your main SELECT into a Common Table Expression (CTE) and then SELECT from that, and put your WHERE clause there.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CROSS/OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tab t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN t.col ... THEN
                          -- very complex conditions
                    END
            ) sub(c)
WHERE sub.c = ?;
```

This approach allows you to avoid nested subqueries.

Comment: I think `VALUES()` makes this much more elegant than a second `SELECT`.

Answer (score 2):

You can put your statement in a cte:

```
; with CTE as (Select .... as X from ...)

Select *
from CTE
where X = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

How about even simpler? Your case expression is returning a bit. Seems to me that if you need a where clause there is no need to run the case expression more than once.

```
select MyReturn = 1
from SomeTable
where case with a whole bunch of logic end = 1
```

Or if you need it to be parameterized something like this.

```
select MyReturn = @MyBit
from SomeTable
where case with a whole bunch of logic end = @MyBit
```

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't a subquery work just fine?

```
SELECT ST.*
  FROM (SELECT TBL.*,
               CASE WHEN ComplexCondition THEN 'Something' 
                    ELSE 'SomethingElse'
                END AS aliasedColumn
          FROM SomeTable
       ) ST
 WHERE ST.aliasedColumn = 'Something';
```