# Getting Invalid Column Name in Azure SQL Data Warehouse

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I created an alias and checked whether alias column is null or not null but alias is not working in sql data warehouse.

```
select (emp_id)  a

from dbo.test b

where a is not null

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'a'.
```

Comment: Where emp_id is not null

Comment: @JohnCappelletti thanks for your response but why we need alias?

Comment: You don't NEED the alias A.  You just can't reference the alias in the where

Comment: If I have a multiple columns and I need check whether its null or not then Do I need to write multiple condition after where statement?  where emp_id is not null, emp_name is not nul,age is not null instead of select (emp_id,emp_name,emp_age) a from dbo.test b where a is not null

Answer (score 0):

You can't Use alias as simple as in `where` clause. But there are other ways which you can implement it

- Using CTE
- CROSS APPLY/OUTER APPLY

There are good examples at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause) for you to look-out