# Doing a full text research and limit the records returned by the rank number

Tags: sql, postgresql, alias, postgresql-10

in Postgresql 10, I'm doing a full text search and I want not to receive records when the `rank` is below a predefined number.

```
 SELECT i.id, i.slug, i.name, i.short_description,
    ts_rank(
        setweight(to_tsvector(COALESCE(i.name, '')), 'A') || 
        setweight(to_tsvector(COALESCE(i.short_description, '')), 'B') || 
        setweight(to_tsvector(COALESCE(i.description, '')), 'B') || 
        setweight(to_tsvector(COALESCE(o.name, '')), 'C') || 
        setweight(to_tsvector(COALESCE(o.short_description, '')), 'D'),
    plainto_tsquery('balenare')) AS rank 
    FROM items_item AS i INNER JOIN owners_owner AS o 
    ON i.owner_id = o.id 
    WHERE i.is_active = true AND rank > 10000
    ORDER BY rank DESC
```

I get an error, because I added the condition `rank > 10000`

> ERROR: column "rank" does not exist

which is true, but I still want to use the rank as a limit

Comment: The solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause

Comment: Or just wrap the query without the `WHERE rank` part in another SELECT which applies the rank filtering and ordering.