# I am getting sql error while trying to check the (sales id NOT IN sales details to check if there is any sales without a details )

Tags: sql

```
select id as sales_id 
from sl_sales 
where  sales_id not in (select sales_id from sl_sales_dtls  )
```

Why above sql is wrong. I need to check if there is any sales without a  details.
Can any one guide me

Comment: You can't use a column alias in the `where` clause. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsql%5D+column+alias+where+)

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: ooo i thought using column alias can make easier sql call , any solution @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use aliases you have created in the same scope you have created them in. You need this:

```
select id as sales_id 
from sl_sales 
where id not in (select sales_id from sl_sales_dtls)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to write this query, without using inline statement.

```
select S.id as sales_id 
from sl_sales S
 Left join sl_sales_dtls D on S.id=D.sales_id
Where D.sales_id is null
```

Comment: thank you @Joe Ipe  but I was trying to get around without using the join

Answer (score 1):

I would use `NOT EXISTS` instead :

```
select sl.id as sales_id 
from sl_sales sl
where not exists (select 1 from sl_sales_dtls dt where dt.sales_id = sl.id);
```

`NOT IN` will return no row if `sub-query` have `null` value.