# SQLite computed column in WHERE clause seems to be working(?)

Tags: sql, sqlite, where-clause

The order in which DMBS execute queries is:

`FROM -> JOIN -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT -> ORDER BY -> LIMIT`

I was surprised to find out that this query works well on SQLite:

```sql
SELECT *, duration / 60 AS length_in_hours
FROM movies
WHERE length_in_hours > 10;
```

Why is this query working, while in some [other cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause) it seems to fail?

Comment: Because SQLite != SQL Server. Every DB engine as different features and even a different SQL dialect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, So I run `EXPLAIN` to see what's going on here.

```
.eqp full
PRAGMA vdbe_trace=true;
```

```sql
EXPLAIN
SELECT substr(name, 1, 1) AS initial
FROM names
WHERE initial = 'D';
```

The query results are:

```
addr  opcode         p1    p2    p3    p4             p5  comment      
----  -------------  ----  ----  ----  -------------  --  -------------
0     Init           0     11    0                    0   Start at 11  
1     OpenRead       0     7     0     2              0   root=7 iDb=0; names
2     Rewind         0     10    0                    0                
3       Column         0     1     2                  0   r[2]=names.name
4       Function       6     2     1     substr(3)    0   r[1]=func(r[2..4])
5       Ne             5     9     1                  80  if r[1]!=r[5] goto 9
6       Column         0     1     7                  0   r[7]=names.name
7       Function       6     7     6     substr(3)    0   r[6]=func(r[7..9])
8       ResultRow      6     1     0                  0   output=r[6]  
9     Next           0     3     0                    1                
10    Halt           0     0     0                    0                
11    Transaction    0     0     10    0              1   usesStmtJournal=0
12    Integer        1     3     0                    0   r[3]=1       
13    Integer        1     4     0                    0   r[4]=1       
14    String8        0     5     0     D              0   r[5]='D'     
15    Integer        1     8     0                    0   r[8]=1       
16    Integer        1     9     0                    0   r[9]=1       
17    Goto           0     1     0                    0
```

In `addr` 0, the `Init` opcode sends us to `addr` 11 which open new `Transaction`.

Right after that SQLite allocate the integer 1 *FOUR TIMES* (`addr` 12-13, 15-16). That's where I started to suspect SQLite may artificially duplicate the expression before the `AS` into the `WHERE` clause.

In opcodes 3-5, which happen before the `SELECT` (opcodes 6-8), we can see that SQLite duplicated our `substr` into the `WHERE` clause.