# Alias in where clause and the group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I select one column which I group and the sum of prices which I want to alias in order to use them in the condition.

The problem is in **WHERE** as it cant be aliased there but even the [Parenthesis/Subselect (Which is the answer to the similar question)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8370146/14833668) example does not help because at the end order by would not work.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT product_status, SUM(list_price) as sum_prices
FROM OE.PRODUCT_INFORMATION
WHERE (LOWER(product_status) NOT LIKE '%orderable%') AND (sum_prices >= 4000)
GROUP BY product_status;
```

Output:

```
ORA-00904: "SUM_PRICES": invalid identifier
```

Comment: This could be helpful: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp

Comment: Thanks it was really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use an alias in the `WHERE` clause; you would need to use the full un-aliased expression instead. However, that will not work here as the expression you have aliased is an aggregation and the `WHERE` filters are evaluated before the `GROUP BY` and you need to filter on the result of the aggregation after the `GROUP BY`; that is what the `HAVING` clause is for, filtering after `GROUP`ing.

So, either use `HAVING` and repeat the aggregation expression:

```sql
SELECT product_status,
       SUM(list_price) as sum_prices
FROM   OE.PRODUCT_INFORMATION
WHERE  LOWER(product_status) NOT LIKE '%orderable%'
GROUP BY product_status
HAVING SUM(list_price) >= 4000;
```

Or wrap it in a sub-query then you can use the alias in the outer query.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT product_status,
         SUM(list_price) as sum_prices
  FROM   OE.PRODUCT_INFORMATION
  WHERE  LOWER(product_status) NOT LIKE '%orderable%'
  GROUP BY product_status
)
WHERE  sum_prices >= 4000;
```