# SQL Select AS not being recognized as column

Tags: sql, select

I am using a simple `select` statement and creating a column using a `CONCAT` function and labeling the column as `Filter`.

Why is the new column not being recognized?

Error message states

> Invalid Column Name - Filter

[image]

Comment: What specific DMBS? Some require you to add a keyword before a calculated field or some have reserved key words. I can see either being an issue here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Comment: Your IDE (presumably SQL Server SSMS) is displaying your column alias in blue - this *means* it's a reserved keyword so you should delimit it `[Filter]` however the above explanation is probably your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to column aliases in the `where` clause as the `where` is processed *before* the alias is materialised.

There are several workarounds, and assuming SQL Server you can do

```
select *
from table t
cross apply (values(concat(columna,columnb)))c([filter])
where [filter]='something'
```

Also note that the performance won't be great on large data sets since this criteria is *non-sargable*