# How to include attribute created by CASE WHEN in the WHERE clause in HIVE?

Tags: sql, hive

This is a simple example of the problem:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a = 5 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS x
FROM table
WHERE x = 0;
```

I will get an error message that x is not amongst the possible column names.
Could anyone advise me how to solve this?

Comment: in some DB like MySQL, this works but in hive this doesnt. You can use CTE or use the select in a inner query and use it in outer qry. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN a = 5 THEN 0 
   ELSE 1 
END AS x FROM table 
WHERE 
 CASE WHEN a = 5 THEN 0 
   ELSE 1 
END=0
```