# Is it possible to label group conditions in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, column-alias

example pseudo-sql

```
SELECT *, condlabel FROM tbl WHERE cond1:(col1 = 1) OR cond2:(col2 = 2 and col3 = 4)
```

so the results will have additional column with exact condition label which they are satisfy

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `SELECT ... AS x` ?

Comment: multiple SELECT ... AS x ? like UNION ? i think it's last case cause of multiple scans will burn out db

Comment: No, `UNION` is used to concatenate multiple query result sets. You could just add your conditions in the `SELECT` clause like this: `col1 = 1 AS cond1`.

Answer (score 0):

as AymDev commented, perfect solution is to add conditions in select block with `as` aliasing

Answer (score 0):

No, you can only label (create aliased expressions) in a `SELECT` clause, and [you cannot use those in a `WHERE` clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause), but you can use a subquery to achieve this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT *, (col1 = 1) AS cond1, (col2 = 2 and col3 = 4) AS cond2
   FROM tbl
) AS tmp
WHERE cond1 OR cond2
```

Alternatively just repeat them:

```
SELECT *, (col1 = 1) AS cond1, (col2 = 2 and col3 = 4) AS cond2
FROM tbl
WHERE (col1 = 1) OR (col2 = 2 and col3 = 4)
```