# Efficient SQL insertion of derived value and look up

Tags: sql, hive, databricks

How can I efficiently perform a where on a derived variable. For example I am computing `event_date` to insert into a table. But I want to use this variable I compute at this stage in the `where` clause. Is there an efficient way to do this rather than compute it again?

```
insert into table {table} 
(
  event_header_event_id 
, event_date 
) 
select 
  cs.event_header_event_id as event_header_event_id
, try_cast(concat(cs.year, "-", cs.month, "-", cs.day) as string) as event_date
from source_table cs where event_date  >= date_add(current_date(), -{daysback} );
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Referring to a Column Alias in a WHERE Clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8370114/referring-to-a-column-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [date_sub function](https://docs.databricks.com/en/sql/language-manual/functions/date_sub.html#date_sub-function) in databricks.
Here's an example:

```
insert into table {table} 
(
  event_header_event_id 
, event_date 
) 
select cs.event_header_event_id as event_header_event_id,
try_cast(concat(cs.year, "-", cs.month, "-", cs.day) as string) as event_date
FROM events
WHERE event_date > date_sub(current_date(), daysback);
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The question was relating to using `event_date` in the `where` clause, not a better way of doing `date_add(current_date(), -{daysback} )`