# SQL.. Alias name in where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using an Alias in a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356675/using-an-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Please let me know why i'm not able to use the alias names in where condition for the query below..

```
SELECT * FROM (        
    SELECT USER_NAME AS "User ID",
         OLD_VALUE_STRING as "Status",
         NVL(lag(ENTRY_DATE) over (partition by user_name order by ENTRY_DATE), trunc(Sysdate-1)) as "Begin", 
           ENTRY_DATE as "End"
         FROM (SELECT U.USER_NAME,
                 U.FULL_NAME,
                 UH.OLD_VALUE_STRING,
                 UH.NEW_VALUE_STRING,
                 UH.ENTRY_DATE,
                 US.IS_WORKING
            FROM VIW.USER_HISTORY UH, VIW.USERS U, VIW.USER_STATUS US
           WHERE U.ID = UH.USER_ID
             AND UH.EVENT_ID = VIW.EVENT_PKG.GET_ID('UPD_USR_STATUS')
             AND UH.NEW_VALUE_STRING = US.ABBREVIATION
             AND UH.ENTRY_DATE >= TO_DATE('01082013', 'MMDDYYYY')
             AND UH.ENTRY_DATE <= TO_DATE('01092013', 'MMDDYYYY')
           ORDER BY U.USER_NAME, UH.ENTRY_DATE) 

    UNION        

    SELECT USER_NAME AS "User ID",
         NEW_VALUE_STRING as "Status",
         ENTRY_DATE AS "Begin", 
           lead(ENTRY_DATE) over (partition by user_name order by ENTRY_DATE) as "End"
           FROM (SELECT U.USER_NAME,
                 U.FULL_NAME,
                 UH.OLD_VALUE_STRING,
                 UH.NEW_VALUE_STRING,
                 UH.ENTRY_DATE,
                 US.IS_WORKING
            FROM VIW.USER_HISTORY UH, VIW.USERS U, VIW.USER_STATUS US
           WHERE U.ID = UH.USER_ID
             AND UH.EVENT_ID = VIW.EVENT_PKG.GET_ID('UPD_USR_STATUS')
             AND UH.NEW_VALUE_STRING = US.ABBREVIATION
             AND UH.ENTRY_DATE >= TO_DATE('01082013', 'MMDDYYYY')
             AND UH.ENTRY_DATE <= TO_DATE('01092013', 'MMDDYYYY')
           ORDER BY U.USER_NAME, UH.ENTRY_DATE)               
)  as innerTable
           WHERE Status <>'LOGGED_OUT'     
           ORDER BY 1,3
```

Comment: Because that's not something that SQL allows you to do... Read the documentation.

Comment: +1@JordanKaye You may use a `case`... here some other [relevant posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356675/using-an-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Comment: Why can't you use `innerTable.NEW_VALUE_STRING<>'LOGGED_OUT' `? (Or did I just read it wrong?)

Comment: You can use table alias but you can't use column alias...Also try to move query into an inline view `without the where-clause predicate`, and then add the where-clause predicate, using the alias, in the outer query...

Comment: BTW, you should consider using JOINS in your FROM statement.

Comment: @popnoodles: I think the user is referring to the `STATUS` in the 2nd to last line, which is an alias coming from the SELECT.

Comment: Yes, which they've create from `NEW_VALUE_STRING` from the table with alias `innerTable`. i.e. `Status` in the where clause == `innerTable.NEW_VALUE_STRING`

Comment: user1430989 could you update the question to clarify that you are talking about the STATUS alias (if that's true)?  This will help you question (if true).

Comment: Implicit joins are a SQL antipattern. Why are you still using them?

Answer (score 3):

All the stuff in the FROMs and JOINS and the WHERE is used to produce all the stuff for  the SELECT.  So you can't uses aliases from the SELECT in the WHERE, because the WHERE is logically prior.  The rows presented to the SELECT come after the WHERE was already applied.

So `Status` isn't known to the WHERE at all.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself. Thank your for your time though.

```
SELECT * FROM (        
    SELECT USER_NAME AS "User ID",
         OLD_VALUE_STRING as "STATUS",
         NVL(lag(ENTRY_DATE) over (partition by user_name order by ENTRY_DATE), trunc(Sysdate-1)) as "Begin", 
           ENTRY_DATE as "End"
         FROM (SELECT U.USER_NAME,
                 U.FULL_NAME,
                 UH.OLD_VALUE_STRING,
                 UH.NEW_VALUE_STRING,
                 UH.ENTRY_DATE,
                 US.IS_WORKING
            FROM VIW.USER_HISTORY UH, VIW.USERS U, VIW.USER_STATUS US
           WHERE U.ID = UH.USER_ID
             AND UH.EVENT_ID = VIW.EVENT_PKG.GET_ID('UPD_USR_STATUS')
             AND UH.NEW_VALUE_STRING = US.ABBREVIATION
             AND UH.ENTRY_DATE >= TO_DATE('01082013', 'MMDDYYYY')
             AND UH.ENTRY_DATE <= TO_DATE('01092013', 'MMDDYYYY')
           ORDER BY U.USER_NAME, UH.ENTRY_DATE) 

    UNION        

    SELECT USER_NAME AS "User ID",
         NEW_VALUE_STRING as "STATUS",
         ENTRY_DATE AS "Begin", 
           lead(ENTRY_DATE) over (partition by user_name order by ENTRY_DATE) as "End"
           FROM (SELECT U.USER_NAME,
                 U.FULL_NAME,
                 UH.OLD_VALUE_STRING,
                 UH.NEW_VALUE_STRING,
                 UH.ENTRY_DATE,
                 US.IS_WORKING
            FROM VIW.USER_HISTORY UH, VIW.USERS U, VIW.USER_STATUS US
           WHERE U.ID = UH.USER_ID
             AND UH.EVENT_ID = VIW.EVENT_PKG.GET_ID('UPD_USR_STATUS')
             AND UH.NEW_VALUE_STRING = US.ABBREVIATION
             AND UH.ENTRY_DATE >= TO_DATE('01082013', 'MMDDYYYY')
             AND UH.ENTRY_DATE <= TO_DATE('01092013', 'MMDDYYYY')
           ORDER BY U.USER_NAME, UH.ENTRY_DATE)               
) 
           WHERE STATUS <>'LOGGED_OUT'     
           ORDER BY 1,3
```