# Decode with alias name in cursor

Tags: plsql

I want to use decode function in cursor with alias names to avoid column ambiguity so i used below approach.

I have code such as:

```
 declare
     cl number;
     cursor c is 
        select c1.rowid,c1.col1,
               DECODE(c1.col2, 'XYZ', c1.col3, 10) cl 
          from table1 d,table2 c1 where c1.process_id=13525 and d.col3(+)=cl;
begin
  for rec in c
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(NVL(rec.cl,'-1'));
  end loop;
end;
```

In this, when i will fire query by removing condition 'and d.col3(+)=cl' it will retrieve me data with the value of 'cl' . But when i assign this condtion it will not retrive data and not go in for loop of cursor.I have a matching data in d.col3.

Suppose if i will get cl as 5 then it is also present in d.col3 then it should give me data i did this because i need to remove duplicate records.Because with that single condition i will get duplicate records.Here col3 in d table is as primary key.

So i am not getting why it will not go in for loop as it gets value from query.

Comment: No there is not any error message.It does not go in loop because it does not retrive any data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using an Alias in a WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/356675/using-an-alias-in-a-where-clause)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use alias in `WHERE` clause: [Using an Alias in a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356675/using-an-alias-in-a-where-clause)

In such cases, a sub-query or a CTE might help. Something *like* that (untested!):

```
with V as (
  select c1.rowid rid, ,c1.col1, c1.process_id,
         DECODE(c1.col2, 'XYZ', c1.col3, 10) cl 
    from table2 c1)

select V.rid, V.col1, V.cl from table1 d,V 
  where V.process_id=13525 and d.col3(+)=V.cl;
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting suggestion that using WITH clause, My approach to retrieve data through DECODE() using alternative table name is:

```
  declare
     cl number;
     cursor c is 
        with V as (
           select c1.process_id,
                  DECODE(c1.col2, 'BANDM', c1.col3, 10) cl 
             from table2 c1)
           select c1.rowid rid,c1.col1, V.cl from table1 d,V,table2 c1
            where V.process_id=1 
              and d.col3(+)=V.cl 
              and c1.col3=V.cl;

  begin
    for rec in c
    loop
     dbms_output.put_line(NVL(rec.rid,'-1'));
     dbms_output.put_line(NVL(rec.cl,'-1'));
    end loop;
  end;
```

Another solution without WITH clause is :

```
  declare
     c2 number;
     cursor c is 
          select c1.process_id
                 c1.rowid,
                 c1.col1,
                 DECODE(c1.col2, 'BANDM', c1.col3, 10) as c2
            from table1 d,
                 table2 c1
           where c1.process_id=1 
             and d.col3(+) = DECODE(c1.col2, 'BANDM', c1.col3, 10);

  begin
    for rec in c
    loop
     dbms_output.put_line(NVL(rec.rid,'-1'));
     dbms_output.put_line(NVL(rec.c2,'-1'));
    end loop;
  end;
```