# Prestashop - List view filter

Tags: mysql, where-clause, alias, prestashop, clause

I insert an other column in the list view of my module inserting the values with getList function, I modified the sql to filter in the renderList function but I can't use the alias in where clause.

How can I fix it?

The error i got is the next:

```
Uncaught Unknown column 'product_supplier_name' in 'where clause'<br /><br />
```

```
 SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.* , s.name AS product_supplier_name FROM ps_supplier_bill a LEFT JOIN ps_supplier s ON s.id_supplier = a.id_product_supplier WHERE 1 AND product_supplier_name LIKE '%fa%' ORDER BY product_supplier_name asc LIMIT 0,50
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper query should be this:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS a.* , s.`name` AS product_supplier_name FROM `ps_supplier_bill` a LEFT JOIN `ps_supplier` s ON s.`id_supplier` = a.`id_product_supplier` WHERE 1 AND s.`name` LIKE '%fa%' ORDER BY s.`name` asc LIMIT 0,50
```

It's not possible use directly an alias in WHERE, because chronologically, WHERE happens before SELECT, which always is the last step in the execution chain. [REFER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356675/using-an-alias-in-a-where-clause)

From MySQL doc:

> Standard SQL disallows references to column aliases in a WHERE clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE clause is evaluated, the column value may not yet have been determined.

[MySQL doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is i don't know how change the where clause to put `s.name` instead `product_supplier_name` for the query