# Oracle: ORA-00936: missing expression, trying to add where statement to selected column

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have a SQL query that works just fine for getting info of the past 2 years out of our database the problem comes up when I try to add a statement that adds a new condition to the SQL.

```
where ASSIGNED_REP = 'PERSON, SOME',
```

Maybe I am doing this wrong but one of the columns I am pulling from is set up like this:

```
name_full AS ASSIGNED_REP,
```

So I figured if I added the where statement it should only return results where that column contains the username I gave it. However I am getting the error `Oracle: ORA-00936: missing expression`.

My SQL works perfectly until I added `where ASSIGNED_REP = 'PERSON, SOME'` to it on the 4th line.

I am new to SQL so I am sure I am missing something.

Full SQL:

```
select 
ccc.BID AS B_ID,
TTTT,
name_full AS ASSIGNED_REP where ASSIGNED_REP = 'PERSON, SOME', /* issue is here */
bbb.CUID,
bbb.BNN,
bbb.PGN,
ccc.TYP_CD AS CLM_TYP,
ccc.C_TYP AS SCLM_TYP,
C_DATE,
NEXT_DATE,
SUM(ccc.LINE) AS line_items,
SUM(ccc.AMT) AS c_amount,
SUM(ccc.CO_RSLVD) AS Z_RSLVD,
SUM(ccc.CU_RSLVD) AS C_RSVLD,
ccc.STATUS_TYP AS STATUS,
DATE_FOLLOW_UP,
bbb.STATE
from bstatus bbb
join display_view ccc on ccc.bnn = bbb.bn
left join user_profile up on uuu.zz_id = ccc.ASSIGNED_USER_ID
where ccc.C_DATE >= (sysdate - 730)
/* Also tried */
/* and ASSIGNED_REP = 'PERSON, SOME' */
group by ccc.BID,
TTTT,
uuu.name_full,
bbb.CUID,
bbb.BAN,
bbb.PGN,
ccc.TYP_CD,
ccc.C_TYP,
C_DATE,
NEXT_DATE,
ccc.STATUS_TYP,
DATE_FOLLOW_UP,
bbb.STATE
```

Comment: Use `AND` instead of  `,`.

Comment: Please Show the complete statament. you can not use an alias from `select` clause in `where`!

Comment: You can not add a WHERE condition based on an alias, but you need to refer to the column: `WHERE name_full = …`

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356675/using-an-alias-in-a-where-clause

Comment: maybe the extra comma at the end? maybe you are trying to use an alias? Maybe you are typing `where`multiple times? Lots of maybes is what you are going to get until you post the entire sql statement.

Comment: Sorry about the SQL statement. I had to take some time to modify it as to no show any company info. It has been added now.

Comment: You already have a `where` clause; you can't just tack another one in the middle of the select list. If you want to look for a specific name you should do that as part of the existing `where` clause, as `and name_full = 'PERSON, SOME'`

Comment: @AlexPoole Currently my code pulls a list of ticket from the past 2 years. What I was trying to add was a simple parameter that checked for a specific rep name assigned to the tickets.

Comment: Just wondering why all the down votes? Is there something wrong with the way my question is formatted? (so I can improve my questions in the future)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure of a query is [pretty well defined](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html). You can't have more than one `where` clause<sup>1</sup>, and it doesn't belong in the middle of the select list.

You want to add another condition, so add it to the existing `where` clause:

```
select 
ccc.BID AS B_ID,
TTTT,
uuu.name_full AS ASSIGNED_REP,
...
where ccc.C_DATE >= (sysdate - 730)
and uuu.name_full = 'PERSON, SOME'
group by ccc.BID,
...
```

Note that you can't use the `ASSIGNED_REP` alias in the where clause, you have to use the original column name. The documentation linked to above also includes (emphasis added):

> ***c_alias***
>
> Specify an alias for the column expression. Oracle Database will use this alias in the column heading of the result set. The `AS` keyword is optional. The alias effectively renames the select list item for the duration of the query. **The alias can be used in the *order_by_clause* but not other clauses in the query.**

So you can `order by ASSIGNED_REP`, but you can't use it in the `where` clause or anywhere else.

---

<sup>1</sup> I'm ignoring subqueries...

Comment: Thanks Alex. For some reason I thought it would be ok to use the alias. I didn't realize that was where my issue was.

Comment: @Mike-SMT - I've highlighted the relevant bit from the docs. Don't worry, that's a common mistake *8-)

Comment: Thanks. I have selected your answer as it explains why what I was doing would not work. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. What you want to do here is add to your existing WHERE clause

```
SELECT ccc.BID AS B_ID
    ,TTTT
    ,ASSIGNED_REP
    ,bbb.CUID
    ,bbb.BNN
    ,bbb.PGN
    ,ccc.TYP_CD AS CLM_TYP
    ,ccc.C_TYP AS SCLM_TYP
    ,C_DATE
    ,NEXT_DATE
    ,SUM(ccc.LINE) AS line_items
    ,SUM(ccc.AMT) AS c_amount
    ,SUM(ccc.CO_RSLVD) AS Z_RSLVD
    ,SUM(ccc.CU_RSLVD) AS C_RSVLD
    ,ccc.STATUS_TYP AS STATUS
    ,DATE_FOLLOW_UP
    ,bbb.STATE
FROM bstatus bbb
    JOIN display_view ccc ON ccc.bnn = bbb.bn
    LEFT JOIN user_profile up ON uuu.zz_id = ccc.ASSIGNED_USER_ID
WHERE ccc.C_DATE >= (sysdate - 730)
    AND name_full = 'PERSON, SOME'
GROUP BY ccc.BID
    ,TTTT
    ,uuu.name_full
    ,bbb.CUID
    ,bbb.BAN
    ,bbb.PGN
    ,ccc.TYP_CD
    ,ccc.C_TYP
    ,C_DATE
    ,NEXT_DATE
    ,ccc.STATUS_TYP
    ,DATE_FOLLOW_UP
    ,bbb.STATE
```

Now you will only get tickets for the last two years for person named `PERSON, SOME`

Comment: That looks like it did the trick. My query run with the desired results. Thank you very much. My main issue was using the wrong column name reference. I should have been doing name_full instead of ASSIGNED_REP. I did try to do an AND statement as well before but with the wrong column name.