# QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '.'

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

I want to rewrite this SQL query into JPQL and use JPA Projection:

```
SELECT count(id) as count, status, error_class, error_message, id, settlement_status_raw 
FROM `payment_transactions` 
WHERE `payment_transactions`.`terminal_id` = 16 
AND (created_at > '2019-06-01 00:00:00.000000') 
AND (`payment_transactions`.`status` != 'approved') 
GROUP BY `payment_transactions`.`error_message`  ORDER BY count DESC
```

I tried this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new org.plugin.service.PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO(e.id, count(id) as e.count, e.status, e.error_class, e.error_message) " +
            " FROM payment_transactions e " +
            " WHERE e.terminal_id = :id AND (e.created_at > :created_at) " +
            " AND (e.status != 'approved') " +
            " GROUP BY e.error_message " +
            " ORDER BY e.count DESC")
```

But I get error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting CLOSE, found '.' near line 1, column 96 [SELECT new org.plugin.service.PaymentTransactionsDeclineReasonsDTO(e.id, count(id) as e.count, e.status, e.error_class, e.error_message)  FROM payment_transactions e  WHERE e.terminal_id = :id AND (e.created_at > :created_at)  AND (e.status != 'approved')  GROUP BY e.error_message  ORDER BY e.count DESC]"}}
```

Can you give me some advice how to rewrite this query in JPQL properly?

Comment: Your query is a native query, you have to use `nativeQuery = "true"`

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Mike.F `e.count` is not a valid expression. 
But the statement has more problems:

- `e.id`, `e.status`, `e.error_class` aren't part of the `GROUP BY` so they can't be used in the select. Either add them to the `GROUP BY` or use an aggregate function, like `MAX` or `MIN`.
- You can't define aliases inside a constructor expression.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is the dot at `e.count`.

It seems, it should be `count(e.id) as count`. Maybe `count(1) as count` would return the same result.

Comment: Thanks @Jens for clarification. `count(1)` also works only in native queries.