# Count a specific column using JPA

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to do a findAll jpa query. But one of the columns I want to return is a count.

```
 @Entity 
 public class Dtoclass {
      @Id
       private String id;

       private Long count;
 }
```

How do I do this with count.

I am not using the @Query annotation in my repository interface just JPARepository findAll.

Comment: I don't think it is an entity class. Did you try `countAllBy()` method in your interface?

Comment: But I don’t want to return just a count. The query is like this. SELECT COUNT(1), code from table group by code order by COUNT(1) desc

Comment: @xenteros forgot to tag you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement JPA Projection with count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57147507/implement-jpa-projection-with-count)