# SQL - empty result set for checking if date is past the current date

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a query in MariaDB 10.3 database where there is a field called "expiration_date" that stores a unix timestamp, but if there is no data in the field the default is set to "0".

I'm trying to use a WHERE clause to check the current date against the expiration_date to filter out any records that are past the expiration_date.  Below is what I have.

```
SELECT entry_id, title, (CASE WHEN expiration_date = "0" THEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ELSE FROM_UNIXTIME(expiration_date, "%Y-%m-%d") END) AS expiration_date
    FROM channel_titles
    WHERE CURDATE() < expiration_date
```

This returns and empty result set...  what am I missing?

Comment: Side notes: The standard delimiter for string literals is `'` not `"`. Confusing the two can lead to unexpected results. Then you say that expiration_date contains a unix time. So why do you treat it as a string when comparing it with zero? Shouldn't it be a numeric column? Then, in the where clause, you use expiration_date again, this time comparing it to `CURDATE`, but a unixtime looks like this: 1663113600, while a datetime looks like this: 20220914. It makes no sense to compare these two values unconvertedly. My advice: Don't use unix times in a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a very simple solution to this and it only requires you to change two things from your original query:

1. The first part is your column (`CASE` expression) alias - you should define your alias with something not similar to any of the column names present in the table. From your query, you have a column `expiration_date`in your table and you also set an alias for your `CASE` expression with `expiration_date` as well and since you're using `WHERE`, the query will definitely do the lookup based on your table `expiration_date` column instead of your `CASE` expression. Rename that alias to something like `exp_date`... but doing `WHERE exp_date ...` will return you an error. Refer to the second point below.
2. The second part is your `WHERE` - since you're doing lookup from a `CASE` expression (or perhaps custom generated value/column) with newly assigned alias of `exp_date`, you can't use it in `WHERE`.. well, unless you make the query as a subquery/derived table then do the `WHERE` outside.. but you don't need to. You only need to change `WHERE` to `HAVING` and you should be able to use the `exp_date` and get your result.

So, with those two changes, your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT entry_id, title, 
     (CASE WHEN expiration_date = "0" THEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ELSE 
         FROM_UNIXTIME(expiration_date, "%Y-%m-%d") END) AS exp_date
    FROM channel_titles
    HAVING CURDATE() < exp_date;
```

[demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0KbHWTsM)

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use an alias of `expiration_date` from your `CASE` statement in your `WHERE` clause.

**Two problems with this:**

- You cannot use column aliases in the `WHERE` clause. Refer to this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/356675/using-an-alias-in-a-where-clause).

> `WHERE` happens before `SELECT` in the execution chain.

- Your alias matches an *actual* column name in your table, so your
  `WHERE` clause is not throwing an error regarding your alias, its
  comparing the current date to the `expiration_date` column in the table,
  thus, throwing off your expected result.

**Solutions:**

If you want to use the alias in your `WHERE` clause, there are a few options for you to force SQL to handle the `SELECT` before the `WHERE` clause.

1. You can use a subquery (or subselect) to force logical order of
   operation by using parentheses:

```
  SELECT 
  a.entry_id, 
  a.title,
  a.expiration_date
  FROM
     (SELECT 
      entry_id, 
      title, 
      (CASE WHEN expiration_date = 0 THEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ELSE FROM_UNIXTIME(expiration_date, '%Y-%m-%d') END) AS expiration_date
      FROM channel_titles
     ) a
  WHERE CURDATE() < a.expiration_date
```

2. You can declare your alias in a Common Table Expression ([CTE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/common-table-expressions/)), then `SELECT` it `FROM` the `CTE`:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT 
             entry_id, 
             title, 
            (CASE WHEN expiration_date = 0 THEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ELSE FROM_UNIXTIME(expiration_date, '%Y-%m-%d') END) AS expiration_date
             FROM channel_titles)
  SELECT 
      entry_id, 
      title, 
      expiration_date
      FROM cte
  WHERE CURDATE() < expiration_date
```

3. You can disregard using your alias entirely in your `WHERE` clause and plug in the logic from your `SELECT` statement directly into your `WHERE` clause. However, this may appear redundant from a readability perspective; also, extra processing should be considered when using this approach as well, but if you have a small data set this method will work just fine:

```
SELECT 
  entry_id, 
  title, 
  (CASE WHEN expiration_date = 0 THEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ELSE FROM_UNIXTIME(expiration_date, '%Y-%m-%d') END) AS expiration_date
  FROM channel_titles
WHERE CURDATE() < (CASE WHEN expiration_date = 0 THEN CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY ELSE FROM_UNIXTIME(expiration_date, '%Y-%m-%d') END)
```

**Input:**

| entry_id | title | expiration_date | expiration_date_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 1695513600 | 2023-09-24 |
| 2 | test2 | 0 | 2022-09-15 |
| 3 | test3 | 1662768000 | 2022-09-10 |

**Output:**

| entry_id | title | expiration_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | test1 | 2023-09-24 |
| 2 | test2 | 2022-09-15 |

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/SdZHQABW?hide=48).